# How to recognize recent button tap in android 8.0

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

We can recognize backbutton press using `onBackPressed()`.
Like this, I need to recognize recent button tap.
I want to listen this event before my current application listen `onPause()`.
I tried with `ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS` but it received after the `onPause()` of current application.

Recent button: It shows recent apps list.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You mean to say, you want to detect which was the last button tapped by user?

Comment: I want to recognize recent button tap that shows recent apps list.

Comment: @Sagar no. He is asking about the device's `Recent Apps` button, it is at left side of `Home` button. Please check my answer.